# Determine current status of Unikey: Vietnamese/English typing mode

Tags: autohotkey, code

I am using Unikey from [this website](http://unikey.vn/vietnam/#nav4) to type Vietnamese in TELEX mode in my laptop.

I would like to know whether it is in Vietnamese typing mode or English typing mode so I can use that info to write some program with autohotkey.

Does anyone know how to know its current mode so I can use it for autohotkey in a program?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using AutoHotkey, see this post for detecting TrayIcon info:

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/15918-extract-informations-about-trayicons/

Comment: I cannot download the code as it is expired and also does it show whether unikey is in English or Vietnamese mode?